# Django filtering results based on different model

Tags: django, django-queryset

In my models.py

```
class Packages(models.Model):
      limit = models.PositiveIntegerField()
      ..

class SubscribedPackages(models.Model):
      package = models.ForeignKey(Packages)
      user = ..
      ..
```

in my forms.py

```
package = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Packages.objects.all(),...)
```

Suppose package 1 has limit of 10 and SubscribedPackages contains 10 entries. Then what should be the query in forms.py to show only those packages whose limit has't been reached..

Answer (score 1):

Should be something like this.

```
from django.db.models import Count
Packages.objects.annotate(subs=Count('subscripberpackage')).filter(subs__gt=10)
```